# Best way to avoid multiple queries

Tags: sql, database, performance, optimization, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 to store the data on a smartphone, but currently I'm just testing it.
The tables are:

```
type = 1 Event    : eid (primary key), other columns
type = 2 Location : lid (primary key), other columns
Relation : parent (foreign key), child (foreign key), p_type, c_type
```

The database id of every object is stored within the object. Event object contains a Location object. So whenever the query is to retrieve all Event objects, I need all the location objects associated with the event objects to form the complete object. Since Location is a separate object on its own, I need to have a separate table of Location objects. Event objects may contain other object types, hence we have p_type (parent type) and c_type (child type) to identify the correct object types we want.

so the queries will be something like this:

```
select * from event;
select * from location where id in (select child from relation where c_type = location)
```

This will give me all the event and location objects, but it does not give me the relations between which event and location objects are connected. What I have done is, I have a third query:

```
select parent, child from Relation where c_type = location
```

And then I create a map of these child objects and assign them to the parent objects.
Like add all location objects to Map, then add all event objects to another Map with their keys set to their database id's. Then I iterate through the results from Relation, and set

```
results contain parent, child
Map(parent).addlocation(Map.child)
```

I think I'm complicating the process unnecessarily. My primary concern is efficiency, and ease of passing results back. It is not limited to just these two object types. There can be many more objects, and each object can contain several objects of different types. So I'm trying to figure out a way to make sure that the database is not stuck in a lot of queries, since I'm expecting the database to be queried frequently.

Comment: It's really not an answer but the best way to avoid multiple queries is just knowing the greater intricacies of SQL in general (joins, etc)

Comment: my main concern is performance, so won't joins actually increase the performance times in a smartphone device? Since there would be joins over many tables?

Comment: I would say doing multiple queries and communications to a database (with your own program logic), versus the database doing things in an already optimized way for itself would not be faster.

Comment: but the database cannot create event objects and pass location objects attached to event objects, and what happens if I have multiple objects??